# Showing that $f(r^k)^{-1}=f(r^k)$, where $f$ is a representation of the dihedral group $D_n$

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, dihedral-groups

Let $D_n$ be the dihedral group, which contains elements of the form $\{r^k\}_{k\in K}$ and $\{sr^k\}_{k\in K}$ where $K=\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ and $r$ and $s$ satisfy the equations
$$
r^n=s^2=1,\quad sr^ks=r^{-k}.
$$
I know that if $f$ is a one-dimensional matrix representation of $D_n$, then $f(r^k)\in \{(-1),(+1)\}$. This would suggest that
$$\tag{1}
f(r^k)^{-1}=f(r^k),
$$
but I cannot see why that is true. Can someone help me show equation $(1)$?

Comment: Your representation is one dimensional, hence it makes your elements commute

Comment: Observe that a one-dimensional representation will be a homomorphism from the group to the multiplicative group of whatever the underlying field is. Thus, if you are fine with knowing that $f(r^k)\in\{\pm 1\}$, then since $f$ is a homomorphism you have that if $f(r^k)=\pm1$, then you will haev that $f(r^k)^{-1}=1^{-1}=\pm1$, so we see that $f(r^k)^{-1} = f(r^k)$.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace, I think your answer was basically correct, because I think it is true that $f(r^{-k})=f(r^k)^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes I just needed to add it, (it's done)

Comment: @StevenCreech most representation are complex due to the lack of unity roots in the real field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your representation is one-dimensional, $f(ab) = f(a) f(b) = f(b) f(a) = f(ba)$, thus
$$f(r^k) = f(r^k s^2) = f(sr^k s) = f(r^{-k}).$$

If you add $f(r^{k})^{-1} = f(r^{-k})$, you get $f(r^k)^{-1} = f(r^k)$.

Comment: Sorry did not read well, on my way to do so

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: No problem :) !!